# Dropped Laptop and it won't boot anymore

Tags: laptop

This may not be under its appropriate stackexchange site. A friend of mine accidentally dropped his laptop. I dont know how or when. Now his laptop wont boot anymore. Tried charging. Led won't light up. Fell from approximately 2 feet.

Dell inspirion 5437

Comment: Way too many possibilities for anyone here to give you a really constructive answer.

Comment: I know. But he's desperate. The data in his computer is really important. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: See if you can get the HDD out of the Laptop, then if you have a SATA-to-USB cable around, plug it in to another PC and see if you can access the data, if that's the most important factor here

Comment: @Aung Khant Ko What light doesn't light up? All of them?

Comment: Yes all of them. Even the one that indicates charging

Comment: I did tell him to try unplug and plug in the battery again though. Didn't work

Comment: Eh, there's so many parts which could be the issue. Definitely get the HDD out. The mobo could be dead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks man. I'll tell my friend about it :)

Comment: OK, I'll make a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your collegue is desparate for his data, it is entirely possible that the HDD has survived given that it was only a 2 ft drop, but it may not have.

Obtain a SATA to USB cable (Something like this - http://www.amazon.co.uk/1-Year-Warranty-VicTsing-Adapter-Driver/dp/B00GHJJPEK).

Open up the Laptop ([This is the manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14r-5437_Owner's%20Manual_en-us.pdf)) and remove the HDD.

Then plug the HDD into another PC via the cable, and then try and access the DATA via My Computer.

If the HDD does not appear, or the HDD doesn't spin up etc, then he may have to get it to a Data Recovery company.

Comment: Tick it as the answer if it works or you think it will solve the issue.

Comment: Okay. Will do :)

Comment: He wil look into it later. I think it should help retrieve his data. Thanks ^^

Comment: @AungKhantKo I had a classmate who dropped his laptop off his desk (probably exactly 2 feet) right as class ended. His also did not boot, but I was able to plug the HDD into my desktop and retrieve all of his data. The only damaged part of the disk was the head, where the boot sector resides. Hopefully this works for you too!

Comment: Ok update : sent the laptop to the repairs. The motherboard was damaged

Comment: @Aung Khant Ko Like I thought. Solder on Laptop Mobos isn't very strong nowadays apparently.

I presume that he can get the data easily?

Comment: He managed to retrieve the data which is good news. Thanks